# convert dae to scn with animation

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I successfully import the DAE file with the animations.

After converting the DAE to SCN, the animation is gone. How can I keep (or find) the animation after converting the file?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdbNX.png)

Comment: I've had the same exact thing happen recently. Still working on a solution

Comment: Yea i just started to use DAE files instead. This tutorial is more documentation that I've been able to find on animations in SCN files with objects. https://blog.pusher.com/animating-3d-model-ar-arkit-mixamo/